# Como agregrego una carpeta al build path de eclipse en php que me permita editar el source code pero que funcionen como librerias del proyecto

Tags: php, eclipse

quisiera saber como puedo hacer para dado un proyecto en eclipse de php, agregar una carpeta con codigo que luego es incluido en el codigo principal, y que me permita hacer un open to declaration por ejemplo. seria un directorio con archivos php. y por sobre todas las cosas que me permita editar dichos archivos.
Gracias.

Pablo